# Pyspark Structured Streaming and Kafka source -- no sending mensages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using PySpark to read some data and I'm trying read data coming from Kafka source broker, but there is no results print in PySpark.

I realize that the Kafka sending and the receiving methods are working as expected by broker and consumer.  The problem is read the data which broker is sending at PySpark

Here is my code,

```py
events = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "kafka_stream").option("startingOffsets", "latest").load()

events.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)","topic")

events.writeStream().outputMode("append").format("console").start()
```

As I said there is no record printed in screen. But when I used the socket format, it works normally.

Comment: Works for me. Do not remember to add `.awaitTermination()` after `.start()`. Try to check the message in Kafka with `kafka-console-consumer`. Check the log from Kafka broker. Maybe the rebalance is under way and it may take some time...

Comment: Thanks to answer me David but still not working. I'm think here.  Is there some configuration between zookeeper and spark that I missed? I saying that because  kafka consumer  reads from zookeeper localhost:2181